# What is the difference between web page and fan page on facebook sharedposts list?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can use Graph API Explorer V2.1 to get

fan page https://www.facebook.com/shares/view?id=10152296286407478 sharedposts list `10152296286407478?metadata=1&fields=metadata.fields(type,connections)`,

but I can't get

web page http://mall.suiis.com/event/2014/earthday/data/index.aspx sharedposts list `599825380102019?metadata=1&fields=metadata.fields(type,connections)`.

Using `599825380102019/sharedposts` shows empty data.

How can I get web page sharedposts list?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the OpenGraph type *website* has no connection named *sharedposts*:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=599825380102019%3Fmetadata%3D1%26fields%3Dmetadata.fields(type%2Cconnections)&version=v2.1

Result:

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "type": "opengraphobject:website", 
    "connections": {
      "comments": "https://graph.facebook.com/599825380102019/comments?pretty=0", 
      "likes": "https://graph.facebook.com/599825380102019/likes?pretty=0", 
      "picture": "https://graph.facebook.com/599825380102019/picture?pretty=0"
    }
  }, 
  "id": "599825380102019"
}
```

That's why you get an empty result when querying `/599825380102019/sharedposts`.

Comment: Thks ,but this `706866082729351?metadata=1` show **opengraphobject:article** is the same. Is it about **opengraphobject:xxx** no sharedposts?

Comment: I don't think that you can access `/sharedposts` on OpenGraph objects, at least I can find nothing in the docs. There's an overall share counter if you use the `/?id={url}` endpoint as described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/url